# How to find Full list of Facebook ID and names of Cities from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

How can I use the Facebook Ads API to find a comprehensive list of all the cities that can be targeted for ads, and what parameters should I use in my request to ensure that I receive accurate and up-to-date information?

I tested the following parameter in Facebook Graph API Explorer, and its returned an empty Result, but it displays a complete list of countries when I change location_types=['country']

```
search?location_types=["city"]&transport=cors&type=adgeolocation
```

Is there a CSV for all the geolocation details for Facebook? How can I get a List of all cities Facebook Ads GeoLocation has?

Comment: I don't know if they provide a full list anywhere, but you can search for cities using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search#cities

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the `targetingsearch` endpoint in the Graph API explorer with the following fields:

- `type`: set to `adgeolocation` to search for geographic locations.
- `location_types`: set to `city` to retrieve cities.
- `limit`: set to a high number to retrieve all the cities (e.g., 10000).
- `fields`: specify the fields you want to retrieve (e.g., `name`, `country_code`).

Following is an example search path you can try

`/act_{ad_account_id}/targetingsearch?location_types=["city"]&type=adgeolocation&limit=10000&fields["name,country_code"]`

Make sure you're using a user access token or a page access token with `ads_management` permission. Also you need to replace `{ad_account_id}` with the ID of the ad account you want to retrieve targeting information for.

I do not think Facebook provides a CSV of all geolocations but you can use the JSON response from above to convert to CSV using free tools online such as this one - https://data.page/json/csv